Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\sin(xy)\left(\frac{x^3-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)$ without polar coordinates
I have this limit in two variables:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\sin(xy)\left(\frac{x^3-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)$$
Now I know that $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$ and $$|xy|\leq x^2+y^2\quad  \text{Cauchy-Schwarz inequality}, \quad t\in\Bbb R, t\to 0 \implies |\sin(t)|\leq |t|$$ I suspect that the limit is $0$ but I am not sure. Peraphs I must to consider a straight line $y=mx$ and compute the limit for $x\to 0$?
However
$$0\leq \left|\sin(xy)\left(\frac{x^3-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)-0\right|$$$$\leq \left|\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\leq \left|\frac{(x^2+y^2)(x^3-y^5)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|=\left|\frac{x^3-y^5}{x^2+y^2}\right|$$
But I am not able to have an upper bound for the
$$\left|\frac{x^3-y^5}{x^2+y^2}\right|$$
Peraphs here do I must use the polar coordinates?
I have changed my way in another manner taking the polar coordinates $x=\rho\cos \theta$ and $y=\rho\cos \theta$ having:
$$0\leq\left|\sin(\rho^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)\left(\frac{\rho^3\cos^3\theta-\rho^5\sin^5\theta}{\rho^4}\right)\right|$$$$\leq \left|(\rho^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)\left(\frac{\rho^3\cos^3\theta-\rho^5\sin^5\theta}{\rho^4}\right)\right|=$$$$|\rho\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos^3\theta-\rho^2\sin^5\theta)|\leq \rho|\sin\theta\cos^4\theta|+\rho^3|\cos\theta\sin^6\theta|$$
Now the functions $f(\theta)=\sin\theta\cos^4\theta$ and $g(\theta)=\cos\theta\sin^6\theta$ are defined in a close and limited interval. For the Weierstrass theorem we have the $\max$ for every function $f$ and $g$. We called $M=\max_{\theta\in[0,2\pi]}f(\theta)$ and $N=\max_{\theta\in[0,2\pi]}g(\theta)$
and
$$\leq \rho|\sin\theta\cos^4\theta|+\rho^3|\cos\theta\sin^6\theta|\leq \rho M+\rho^3N$$
If I consider $\rho\to 0^+$ we have $\rho|\sin\theta\cos^4\theta|+\rho^3|\cos\theta\sin^6\theta|\leq \rho M+\rho^3N \to 0$ and the limit is $0$. Is it correct?

Yes it's correct. Polar coordinates destroy these kind of limits pretty frequently.

@B.A.M Thank you for your feedback.

$$\left|\frac{x^3-y^5}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq\frac{|x|^3+|y|^5}{x^2+y^2}\leq|x|+|y|^3.$$

Hi Sebastiano, the result will not change if you replace $\sin(xy)$ by $xy$.

@zkutch You've right. I have edit now my answer. Thank you very nice.

@Riemann Thank you for your comment. Why you taken $\leq|x|+|y|^3$? I am not able to do this upper bound. Can you explain me better your steps with an answer, please? I not solve these typologies of problem almost 30 years ago.

@hamam_Abdallah Hiiiiii. Thank you for your response.

$$|x|^3+|y|^5\leq(x^2+y^2)(|x|+|y|^3)\implies \left|\frac{x^3-y^5}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq\frac{|x|^3+|y|^5}{x^2+y^2}\leq|x|+|y|^3.$$

@Riemann Thank you very much.

By applying $|\sin t|\le |t|$ we get
$$ |\sin(xy)| {|x^3-y^5|\over (x^2+y^2)^2}\le {x^4\over (x^2+y^2)^2}|y|+{y^4\over (x^2+y^2)^2}y^2|x|\\ \le |y|+y^2|x|$$ Hence the limit is $0$ when $y\to 0$ and $x$ stays bounded, for example $|x|\le 1.$

Hi. I have not understood the reason $ \le |y|+y^2|x|$ . I not solve these typologies of problem almost 30 years ago.

The ratios $x^4/(x^2+y^2)^2$ and $y^4/(x^2+y^2)^2$ are less or equal $1,$ as the denominators are greater than the numerators.

And as if you do (to me seem) $x^4/(x^4\ldots)\leq 1$ and $y^4/(y^4\ldots)\leq 1$

Correct. Or $x^2/(x^2+y^2)\le 1$ so the inequality holds after raising to the second power.

Approved :-)!!+1

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\sin(xy)\left(\frac{x^3-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}\left(\frac{x^4y-xy^6}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)$$
we have :
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} = 1$$
and we have
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\frac{x^4y-xy^6}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^5(\cos^4(\theta)\sin(\theta)-r^2\cos(\theta)\sin^6(\theta))}{r^4 }=0$$
